# Sorting a JSON file by a certain key

Tags: python, json, sorting

I am coding in Python.

I have a `carV.json` file with content

```
{"CarValue": "59", "ID": "100043" ...}
{"CarValue": "59", "ID": "100013" ...}
...
```

How can I sort the file content into

```
{"CarValue": "59", "ID": "100013" ...}
{"CarValue": "59", "ID": "100043" ...}
...
```

using the "ID" key to sort?

I tried different methods to read and perform the sort, but always ended up getting errors like "no sort attribute" or ' "unicode' object has no attribute 'sort'".

Comment: How about you post things you tried and we will guide you further?

Comment: Json is basically a quasi-dictionary and in python you are playing with the data in dict format.  instead of asking a new question, look up and research existing questions about dictionary sorting.

Comment: post the full path to your "leaf" objects (extended json)

Answer (score 7):

There are several steps:

- Read the file using [*json.load()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)
- Sort the list of objects using [*list.sort()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)
- Use a [key-function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function) to specify the sort field.
- Use [*operator.itemgetter()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to extract the field of interest
- Write the data with [*json.dump()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)

Here's some code to get you started:

```
import json, operator

s = '''\
[
  {"CarValue": "59", "ID": "100043"},
  {"CarValue": "59", "ID": "100013"}
]
'''

data = json.loads(s)
data.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('ID'))
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

This outputs:

```
[
  {
    "CarValue": "59",
    "ID": "100013"
  },
  {
    "CarValue": "59",
    "ID": "100043"
  }
]
```

For your application, open the input file and use `json.load()` instead of `json.loads()`.  Likewise, open a output file and use `json.dump()` instead of `json.dumps()`.  You can drop the *indent* parameter as well, that is just to make the output look nicely formatted.

Answer (score 4):

simple and probably faster in case of large data - [pandas.DataFrame.to_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> unsorted = pd.read_json("test.json")
>>> (unsorted.sort_values("ID")).to_json("sorted_test.json")
>>> sorted = unsorted.sort_values("ID")
>>> sorted
   CarValue      ID
1        59  100013
0        59  100043
>>> sorted.to_json("n.JSON")
```